# Vector processing feedback loop in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, geometry-shader

Reading the OpenGL ES 2.0 spec and available extensions there seem to be no way of processing vertices from one buffer into another. The extensions seem to target ES 3.0+ only. The best bet so far seem to be OpenCL with OpenGL interop...

Function may look like this where the enhancement improves quality based on camera properties over multiple frames:

```
vBufferIn=initial, vBufferOut=0
start
enhanceQuality(vBufferIn, vBufferOut) <--- Is there something like this in ES 2.0 with extentions?
renderUsing(vBufferOut)
...
swap(vBufferIn, vBufferOut)
goto start
```

Is there any way of having OpenGL ES 2.0 making vertex in/out processing?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way of having OpenGL ES 2.0 making vertex in/out
>   processing?

No.